# Div height 100% with scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a css way to hav [this](http://reggi.com/clients/dof/) layout sport a 100% height div, meaning that the white will trail down to the bottom of the document not the window. I would like to do this without images and without javascript.

I've tried `html,body{height:100%}` which only applied to the window not the doc.
I've also tried to put a 900px body background image and it was not centered with the container div.

[image]

Comment: I THINK you can use overflow:visible on whatever element contains that white section to achieve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the live site because the URL is conveniently visible inside your image..

Add this CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
#container {
    min-height: 100%
}
```

Comment: The simplest ideas usually are the best ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need something like

```
<html>

<body style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden">

<div id="realbody" style="height: 100%: overflow: auto">
    ... page goes here ...
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This way you disable scroll bars on the actual page body, and all the scrolling tags place "inside" the document on the "realbody" div. With suitable styling on #realbody, you can make the backgrounds stretch as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually force the containing div to continue behind your other divs by using special separator divs with a clear: both; set in them. Like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="left">
        Left
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        Right
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

Use the  where ever you want your wrapper to continue going down.

NOTE: I'm not sure whether W3c says that's good or bad practice, probably bad, BUT it works.

Answer (score 0):

A sticky footer should accomplish this: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 0):

the question is a bit old, 
but, if you don't want to change body and html,
 and need an element with 100% height without scrollbar you can use this on the div:

```
#fullHeightDiv{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Hope this can help someone.